# Is it possible to add a MySQL partition with BIGINT instead of INT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a problem with tables having a field set as INT, and it now needs to support BIGINT. I'm trying to avoid the obvious solution of rebuilding the table with the new datatype, due to limited resources (I don't have enough disk space for the recreation and would also like to avoid the expected down-time period).

What I thought of was adding a partition to the table, that has the same structure but has all of the rows where field > (2^31 - 1)

Is this possible in any way? I assume the regular partition might not work as is, but is it possible to create some sort of trigger that will provide this flexibility?

Comment: Huh? `ALTER` to `BIGINT` is bad due to resource limitation but having partitioning is not? You're surprising me

Comment: @AlmaDo Maybe I didn't pick the right words. These are hugh tables (biggest is 1TB) and I don't have enough disk-space for the re-creation and would also like to avoid the down-time.